# Interpretation of Canova and Hansen test for seasonal unit-root with R uroot package

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, seasonality, unit-root

**I want to fit a SARIMA model** and have daily sales data with a weekly seasonal pattern (frequency = 7) with this auto correlation function (ACF):

[image]

Clearly, there are **seasonal effects** as the spikes of the ACF indicate. As explained in *(Shumway, Stoffer (2011): Time Series Analysis and its applications. Example 3.46, Figure 3.23.)* the ACF of my time series also indicates seasonal non-stationarity and therefore a unit root in the seasonal component.

After **differencing** at lag $k=7$ ($y_t = y_t - y_{t-7}$) the ACF looks like this:

[image]

Since I wanted to automate this process I wanted to **test for a unit root** with the R package `uroot` using the Canova and Hansen test. This test assumes no unit root in $H_0$

However, when I execute:

```
z <- ts(data[,1], frequency=7)
res <- ch.test(z, type = "dummy", sid = 7)
res
```

I get the result:

```
           Canova and Hansen test for seasonal stability

data:  z

     statistic pvalue  
[1,]    0.1584 0.4785  
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Test type: seasonal dummies 
NW covariance matrix lag order: 12 
First order lag: no 
Other regressors: no  
P-values: interpolation in original tables
```

Am I right assuming that the test gives me a $\text{p-value}=0.4785$ and therefore I cannot reject $H_0$ on a 95% confidence level and therefore have to assume there is no unit root in the seasonal component? And if yes, how does this fit the ACF indicating non-stationarity in the seasonal component? Is there a difference between unit root in the seasonal component and non-stationary seasonal component?

Am I missing/confusing something here?

---

Exemplary plot of the first 30 days:

[image]

All data:

```
[   0, 5530, 4327, 4486, 4997,    0, 7176, 5580, 5471, 4892, 4881,
   4952,    0, 4717, 3900, 4008, 4044, 4127, 5182,    0, 5394, 5720,
   5578, 5195, 5586, 5598,    0, 4055, 3725, 4601, 4709, 5633, 5970,
      0, 7032, 6049, 6140, 5499, 5681, 5370,    0, 4409, 4015, 4252,
   4241, 4809, 6154,    0, 6407, 5386, 5660, 5261, 5000, 5237,    0,
   4038, 3794, 4558, 4676, 4611, 5350,    0, 7675, 6300, 5973, 5637,
   5853, 5578,    0, 4949, 3853, 4341, 5108, 4925, 5003,    0, 7072,
   6563, 5598, 5179, 5506, 5603,    0, 6729, 6686, 6660, 7285,    0,
   7132,    0,    0, 5484, 4625, 4293, 4390, 5075,    0, 6046, 5514,
   4903, 4366, 5263, 4773,    0, 3941, 3357, 3649, 2952, 4303, 4350,
      0, 5672, 4492, 4309, 3939, 4841, 5726,    0, 5821, 5925,    0,
   6486, 6027, 5912,    0, 4568, 4624, 5230,    0, 5409, 5064,    0,
   6106, 5083, 4790, 4448, 4856, 4413,    0,    0, 4789, 3559, 4030,
   4232, 4408,    0, 5519, 4995, 5784,    0, 7893, 5693,    0, 5422,
   5220, 5012, 4881, 4315, 4262,    0, 4291, 3784, 3563, 3661, 4150,
   4766,    0, 5337, 4633, 4180, 5011, 5173, 4341,    0, 3549, 4536,
   3827, 3593, 4407, 5804,    0, 5614, 5868, 5875, 5701, 4986, 4090,
      0, 4475, 4047, 3963, 4053, 4134, 4015,    0, 6377, 5643, 4946,
   4904, 4275, 4421,    0, 4149, 3937, 3849, 3502, 4221, 3352,    0,
   6290, 5773, 5572, 4994, 4494, 4461,    0, 4086, 3582, 4143, 3680,
   3257, 3768,    0, 5326, 5299, 4724, 4575, 4552, 4078,    0, 3954,
   3492, 3096, 3703, 3493, 4752,    0, 5482, 5156, 4583, 4804, 5469,
   5317,    0, 4195, 3928, 3343, 3883, 3836, 4663,    0, 5893, 5403,
   5103, 5079, 5187, 4663,    0, 4249, 3685, 3946, 3717, 3516, 3909,
      0, 4770, 4274, 4212, 4481, 4669, 4175,    0, 4088, 4178, 4001,
      0, 5447, 5352,    0, 6004, 5452, 4957, 5286, 5896, 4954,    0,
   3773, 3355, 3383, 3223, 3566, 3667,    0, 5055, 4068, 4612, 4044,
   4573, 4347,    0, 3557, 3737, 4119, 4035, 5471, 5233,    0, 5861,
   5348, 5572, 5009, 5242, 4681,    0, 4014, 4017, 3310, 3795, 4016,
   5071,    0, 5927, 5143, 4936, 4623, 5058, 5297,    0, 4600, 4201,
   4561, 4614, 5623, 6373,    0, 6943, 6293, 5688, 5691, 6112, 5799,
      0, 4462, 4228, 4301, 4074, 4703, 6119,    0, 8277, 7356, 7821,
   6788, 8414, 8043,    0, 9528, 3204,    0,    0, 6110, 5659,    0,
   7193, 2362,    0, 4969, 4190, 5173,    0, 6194, 5539, 4931, 4396,
   4486, 4454,    0, 3994, 3621, 3776, 3632, 3803, 5128,    0, 6148,
   5151, 4562, 4597, 5098, 4546,    0, 3601, 3581, 3789, 4549, 4906,
   5292,    0, 5839, 5540, 5031, 4823, 5596, 4726,    0, 3591, 3461,
   3662, 3638, 4647, 5258,    0, 5393, 4602, 4935, 4563, 4727, 4820,
      0, 3826, 3499, 4108, 3826, 5031, 5307,    0, 6198, 5397, 4916,
   4585, 5340, 4400,    0, 3573, 3588, 3805, 3224, 3883, 5042,    0,
   5563, 5200, 4036, 4023, 4510, 5241,    0, 3850, 3136, 3225, 3847,
   3987, 4583,    0, 6008, 5407, 4834, 4556, 4738, 4599,    0, 3751,
   3990, 3919, 3948, 3733, 4435,    0, 6803, 6196, 6381, 6160,    0,
   5871,    0,    0, 4133, 3482, 3376, 3710, 3989,    0, 5488, 5923,
   5870,    0, 6790, 5498,    0, 5325, 5055, 5075, 5222, 5237, 5996,
      0, 3957, 3535, 3710, 3589, 3863, 3785,    0, 5637, 4909, 4298,
   3801, 4968, 4574,    0, 3912, 3971, 4616,    0, 5407, 4985,    0,
   6071, 5614, 5229, 5278, 4957, 4923,    0,    0, 4607, 4207, 3702,
   3901, 4757,    0, 4788, 5770, 5256,    0, 6362, 3982,    0, 3755,
   3351, 3727, 2749, 4019, 5162,    0, 5738, 5138, 5161, 4756, 4025,
   5176,    0, 4223, 4081, 3547, 3741, 4020, 4409,    0, 5083, 5298,
   5424, 4685, 4609, 4084,    0, 4507, 3933, 3806, 3557, 3858, 4266,
      0, 5372, 5252, 5487, 5106, 5038, 4731,    0, 5655, 5433, 5337,
   4154, 4451, 4174,    0, 3886, 3185, 4069, 3906, 3746, 4425,    0,
   5623, 5190, 4280, 4327, 3971, 3582,    0, 3414, 3396, 3148, 3920,
   3869, 4094,    0, 5464, 5008, 4978, 4346, 4706, 3959,    0, 3676,
   3377, 3275, 3392, 3906, 4270,    0, 4611, 4381, 4383, 3740, 4128,
   3911,    0, 3982, 3407, 3405, 2462, 3518, 3914,    0, 5280, 4919,
   4712, 5400,    0, 5355,    0, 5402, 5439, 4944, 4654, 4396, 4743,
      0, 4033, 3681, 3775, 3430, 3720, 4169,    0, 4652, 4678, 4868,
   4466, 4196, 4596,    0, 4260, 3364, 3761, 4042, 4161, 6532,    0,
   5857, 5253, 4838, 4785, 5220, 4720,    0, 5474, 4479, 4677, 3869,
   5334, 4967,    0, 3582, 3890, 3894, 4963, 4594, 5849,    0, 6527,
   5815, 5328, 6144, 7195, 7066,    0, 7380, 6467, 6454, 7016, 6207,
   6185,    0, 4884, 4345, 4915, 5060, 5269, 7263,    0, 8069, 7739,
   7523, 7785, 7558, 8367,    0, 9331, 7959, 3659,    0,    0, 6057,
      0, 6463, 6466, 2605,    0, 5509, 5023,    0, 6239, 4574, 4796,
   3716, 3998, 4599,    0, 5346, 4924, 4541, 4295, 4161, 5255,    0,
   3721, 3680, 3299, 3492, 3586, 4840,    0, 4781, 4806, 4310, 5171,
   5577, 5363,    0, 6038, 4901, 4672, 4394, 5022, 4663,    0, 3965,
   3136, 3735, 3900, 4726, 5015,    0, 4303, 4833, 4180, 4460, 4651,
   4475,    0, 3598, 4054, 3875, 4042, 4708, 5289,    0, 5942, 5451,
   5568, 4419, 5397, 4592,    0, 3701, 3805, 4170, 3141, 3725, 5225,
      0, 5695, 4806, 3858, 4748, 4057, 3909,    0, 3565, 3547, 3531,
   3932, 4005, 5208,    0, 6714, 6206, 6816, 6574,    0, 6709,    0,
      0, 4163, 4194, 3467, 3549, 4173,    0, 5377, 4648, 4110, 4116,
   4718, 4594,    0, 3722, 3037, 3319, 3076, 3198, 4318,    0, 5575,
   5199, 5775, 6228,    0, 5850,    0, 5591, 4564, 4960, 4529, 4683,
   4945,    0, 3551, 3547, 3998,    0, 4178, 4431,    0, 5280, 5235,
   4735, 3755, 4459, 4276,    0,    0, 4211, 4083, 4111, 4656, 5592,
      0, 5774, 5450, 5809,    0, 5384, 4183,    0, 4071, 4102, 3591,
   3627, 3695, 4256,    0, 5518, 4852, 4000, 4645, 4202, 4097,    0,
   3846, 3762, 3346, 3533, 3317, 4019,    0, 5197, 5735, 5223, 5558,
   4665, 4797,    0, 4359, 3650, 3797, 3897, 3808, 3530,    0, 5054,
   5042, 4767, 4427, 4852, 4406,    0, 4395, 3558, 3464, 3769, 3706,
   4364,    0, 6102, 5011, 4782, 5020, 5263]
```

EDIT:
I edited the question a couple of times in order to feedback the comments below.

EDIT:
Differencing like suggested above seems the wrong way to go (see comments). Furthermore the statement there is a unit root could not be backed further (see comments). I will look into the OCSB test before writing an answer just to be sure.

Comment: I only have a newer edition of Shumway & Stoffer, so I have not checked the reference, but why do you think there should be a seasonal unit root? The ACF spikes are not that tall, suggesting no seasonal unit root. On the other hand, the ACF 7 or 14 or 21 days ago are similar, perhaps suggesting a seasonal unit root. Did you have a similar intepretation?

Comment: Thank you Richard for your feedback. My interpretation is that at lag 7, 14, 21 and so on i have significant spikes not tailing off. Therefore a non-stationary seasonal component in my SARIMA model. Does this automatically mean there is also a unit-root in the seasonal component? If yes I should be able to reject $H_0$. But I can't. What am I missing/confusing here?

Comment: Now that you added the graph of the original series, it does not look as if it would have a unit root (seasonal or nonseasonal). Then seasonal dummies or seasonal ARMA components could work. But perhaps the picture covers a period that is too short to judge.

Comment: In the end I would like to find a SARIMA (p,d,q))x(P,D,Q)s model. But with the acf not tailing off, I can not really say what my seasonal parameters P and Q look like. Only when differencing I get a nicer acf and can determin the order of my seasonal parameters. Since I would like to automate that process I would like to test for this seasonal non-stationarity. But the test results confuse me.

Comment: Overdifferencing (differencing when it is not justified) is not innocuous. I wonder what the estimated SAR coefficient is is you pick the SAR order `P=1`. And I wonder what `forecast::auto.arima` in R would suggest.

Comment: Your interpretation of the output is correct. The null of stable seasonality is not rejected at the 5% significance level. You can also run the HEGY test for the null of unit roots and see if the conclusion agrees with the CH test; e.g, `hegy.test(z, deterministic=c(1,0,1), lag.method="BIC", maxlag=7)`.

Comment: Around 15% of the observations in the data that you posted are zeros. 
This may require some inspection to find out some explanation and decide whether some action is needed or not (e.g. impute those values with seasonal averages or include some kind of dummy variable).

Comment: The plot `monthplot(z)` shows relatively stable seasonal paths around a horizontal line. This may be compatible with a deterministic seasonal pattern (notice again the zeros).

Comment: If you cannot determine the orders of the ARIMA model by inspection of the ACF, you can fit a grid of models and compare their AIC or BIC.
`forecast::auto.arima` can help you with this.

Comment: Awesome thank you! The zeros can be explained they are not missing values. The data is sales of a shop that is closed on sundays. On those days sales are zero. A dummy will do. I will check HEGY,  `forecast::auto.arima` and `monthplot(z)` asap

Comment: Okay. `forecast::auto.arima` gives me an `ARIMA(2,0,2)(2,0,0)[7] with non-zero mean` model. This supports Richard's view that my idea of differencing seems the wrong way to go. Also, as javlacalle mentioned, monthplot(z) indicates no unit-root in the seasonal component so I skipped HEGY. I will look into the OCSB test to see how `forecast::auto.arima` is determining `D` and write an answer when I am sure about it. For now, thanks a lot for your great input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the ACF shows seasonal spikes with relatively slow decay it can not automatically be concluded that there is a unit-root in the seasonal componend.

Actually ([Ghysels, Osborn (2001): The Econometic Analysis of Seasonal Time Series](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/economics/econometrics-statistics-and-mathematical-economics/econometric-analysis-seasonal-time-series?format=PB&isbn=9780521565882#qCPWk689jCgVOvDe.97), p.29) states:

> "[...] for the sample sizes often observed in practice, it may be difficult to discriminate
>   between deterministic seasonality and a seasonal unit root process."

Furthermore on page 42 they write:

> "It is now well known that a series generated by a unit root process can wander
>   widely and smoothly over time without any inherent tendency to return to
>   its underlying mean value [...]. In the seasonal context, there are S unit root processes, none of which has an inherent tendency
>   to return to a deterministic pattern. As a result, the values for the seasons can wander widely and smoothly in relation to each other [...]"

Therefore it is useful to visualize the time series of the different seasons $S$ and see if they look non-stationary. In our case we have daily data and model each day as a season. So we get seasons $S=7$. Plotting gives:

[image]

None of the single seasonal time series looks particularly non-stationary.

Therefore the Canova and Hansen test statistics is perfectly fine. The same result is obtained when using the `forecast::nsdiffs()` function or the `OCSBtest()` function from [the `R forecast package` source code on github](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/86f92063b50aac65c77d3bad005bd3472c53dd95/R/newarima2.R).